Is there any security issues with WebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(String, String, String, String, String) Method ? How to safeguard webview
I am looking for the security measures to prevent webview from attacks.
I have followed the below link and restricting input urls passing into  webview.loadUrl().
https://medium.com/@kliment.jonceski/secure-android-webviews-best-practices-f110af9aba0c
But in my codebase, i have used LoadDataWithBaseURL to load the html content saved in a app directory but is there any possibility of loading wrong content / assets folder content by attackers will be allowed with this method?. how to safeguard webview in this aspect.
